# Is there a way to skip a specific test case via the command line?

Tags: ant

I am using apache ant, and do not want to change my source tests, but I'd like the option to turn one off. I know that it is possible to only RUN tests you choose (-Dtestcase=whatever), but I'm not sure if you can exclude one.

Answer (score 2):

You might use `ant -DexcludedTest=SomeExcludedTest` and have your batch test configured like this:

```
<batchtest ...>
    <!-- define the excludedTest property to an unexisting test name in case 
         nothing is passed as a system property -->
    <property name="excludedTest" value="THIS_TEST_NAME_DOES_NOT_EXIST"/>
    <fileset dir="${src.tests}">
        <include name="**/*Test.java"/>
        <exclude name="**/${excludedTest}.java"/>
    </fileset>
</batchtest>
```